# What are key differences of GPUs supported by OpenCL/CUDA?

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, opencl, gpu

What had to be changed/added by vendors to make their GPUs suitable to work with OpenCL (or e.g. CUDA)? I know that there are Compute Units and Processing Elements (OpenCL). But GPUs were able to do parallel work before, only without the convenience of being programmed that easily. So what's the key differences architecture wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you asked the question implies that GPU vendors started designing their GPUs to support GPGPU standards, when in fact, GPGPU APIs, like OpenCL or CUDA were developed to expose existing capabilities already present in the hardware. The only major exception is Intel, who will be have OpenCL support for the first time in their Ivy Bridge graphics.

Two big hardware changes that enabled GPGPU, were the additions of floating-point support and more flexible pipelines. The reason why Intel GPUs still do not support OpenCL, is the design of their pipeline that does not easily accommodate non-graphics workloads.

Comment: OK, the question should have cleared it up. It was basically: What were changes (if any) to make it possible. You answered it, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much none, openCL/CUDA is just a compiler layer it compiles down into the same shader units as GLSL

Comment: @talonmies - to the card hw or just to the language?

Comment: To the hardware -- I don't think older designs had TLBs and "proper" virtual addressing support.